# Is the consequence for rape a small sum?

Tags: halacha, money, sexuality

I read somewhere that the consequence for rape, presuming the man does not marry the woman, is just 50 silver sheckels.

This seems like a paltry sum compared to the crime that was committed. Is that all, or is there more?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unless you have a special affinity to the number 2690449, perhaps consider naming your account.

Comment: rapist also may be killed by anyone (for an erva) without trial while trying to rape since he has the status of a rodef. see rambam http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088917/jewish/Rotzeach-uShmirat-Nefesh-Chapter-One.htm

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A biblical *shekel* is 768 *p'ruta* and fifty are [thus 960 grams of silver](/a/27559). That's about US$459.27 today. As Double AA notes (in a comment on the question), though, that's just the fine: the rapist [must also pay actual damages](http://chabad.org/960635).

Comment: And for rape, it's damages, plus 50 shekels, plus he must marry her if she agrees. "You decide, marry her or pay 50 shekels" is for seduction.

Answer (score 8):

Fifty shekels was much more than it's silver content indicates - a worker's daily salary was somewhere between 1/2 and one dinar - fifty shekels was 200 dinars.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Comment: Nice point. That would make 50 shekels about one-year's salary or even more.

Comment: Excellent point. Incidentally, what is your source for workers' daily salaries?

Comment: @Mevaqesh We find examples in Bava Metzia in chapter השוכר את הפועלים.